# hosting wcf service on localhost iis

Tags: wcf, iis, localhost

I am working on an Asp.Net application which will interact with WCF services that will be hosted on local machines on IIS.

In order to make these wcf services be hosted, what rights does user have to have when they log in? Do they have to have Admin rights on the machine?

P.S.: I know that WCF services should not be hosted on individual local machines so please do not start the discussion on that. All i want to know is what rights logged in user needs to have in order to make WCF services available to the application.

Comment: Are you using Impersonation in your WCF service and relying on Windows users/groups to handle file/folder security?

Comment: well. thats the idea. I dont want to let anonymous users consume the service.

Comment: If you dont want anonymous users access the service you need to implement some form of authentication on your service level to determine the access. You can do that with username password validation or certificates

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you set up the service. You can configure the website to allow anonymous access and set up your WCF binding to basicHttp binding with a security mode of None. That should allow any logged in user to run the site. This would NOT restrict users to only the one(s) logged in to the local machine, if that is what you are looking for.

You are dealing with two levels of security here. You will define your access in IIS to allow users to use the site. Then you will set up WCF service to allow the IIS site to access it. If you are using pass through authentication then you will need to authorize the individual users, perhaps with a local group?? Otherwise you need to authorize the identity that IIS is running the site under. So users do not need to be administrators, unless you specifically demand that role in IIS or WCF.

Comment: I expanded my answer based on the comments and after realizing i had not specifically adressed the adminissue.